# JSONRequestOperationWithRequest issue from the AFNetWorking

Tags: iphone, afnetworking

I am doing a reading on the AFNetworking project and I am being stuck at this point:

```
(AFJSONRequestOperation *)JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
                                                    success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON))success 
                                                    failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON))failure
```

Can someone tell me what this method does and what the parameters (with ^ at front of each) are?

Answer (score 3):

JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:

Creates and returns an AFJSONRequestOperation object and sets the specified success and failure callbacks.

```
-(AFJSONRequestOperation *)JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
                                                    success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON))success 
                                                    failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON))failure
```

- Parameters

  - urlRequest
    The request object to be loaded asynchronously during execution of the operation
- success
  A block object to be executed when the operation finishes successfully. This block has no return value and takes three arguments: the request sent from the client, the response received from the server, and the JSON object created from the response data of request.
- failure
  A block object to be executed when the operation finishes unsuccessfully, or that finishes successfully, but encountered an error while parsing the resonse data as JSON. This block has no return value and takes three arguments: the request sent from the client, the response received from the server, and the error describing the network or parsing error that occurred.

Return Value
A new JSON request operation